# Is there a way to create a numeric variable from a numeric set of measurements with different ranges?

Tags: numerics, variable

I am working with a dataset that contains limnological parameters. One of them is turbidity-related measures in different units and consequently different ranges. Is there a way to create a numerical variable called "Turbidity" that comprises all the measurements in different units? I want to use this variable in a linear regression to assess its relationship with plankton parameters.

Edit: I can not just use the measures together in different units because it will create a range that goes from 0.1 to 1000 in absolute numbers and some turbidity units are high at 10. I also don´t want to use them separately because each has only a few measurements, so I´m trying to make my dataset more robust.

Reprex

| values | unit | abundance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.5 | x | 500 |
| 10 | x | 30 |
| 50 | y | 50 |
| 100 | y | 100 |
| 30 | z | 20 |
| 60 | z | 60 |
| 500 | z | 80 |
|  |  |  |

Comment: Why not just include all the limnological parameters in your model?  It would help us to have a better understanding of the problem you face and what you hope to accomplish, so please feel free to include more information in an edit to your post.

Comment: I just added more details to the question and explained that I can not just include them all separately because I want to make a regression with another numeric variable (plankton abundance response), and would not have enough points to make it robust.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to reply to this unless they know what Kd, NTU, TSS and FTU mean but in principle if different units are related by a conversion factor that's an answer in those cases; otherwise you need some kind of regression to get an empirical relation. (Note: I suspect that "unities" and "units" alike refer to units of measurement.)

Comment: Can you just convert to common units like you would if you had some distance measurements in feet and others in meters?

Comment: In general, feature engineering is perfectly acceptable. In practice, you'll likely need some domain knowledge to determine what is a meaningful combination of features. Your issue of missing data will likely not be fixed with feature engineering, however - an aggregate feature often can't be computed if any of its components are missing. If you define "turbidity" to depend on some variable, you're equally stuck if that variable is missing.

Comment: Please do not repost your question, because that loses the comments and makes everyone start all over with their responses.  Just edit this version.

Comment: @whuber I deleted the previous one! Thought it wouldn´t be a problem. Thanks for helping. I´m new here!

Comment: Understood.  It begins to sound like you might have an *imputation* or *missing value* problem, making it likely that with a little more detail from you, readers will be able to provide helpful advice.  The ranges of your variables don't matter at all.

Comment: @NickCox  I removed the acronyms since they are not absolutely needed to solve the question and could cause confusion. The units are not related by any conversion factor that I know : / For what I am understanding, I could combine them in regressions. How can I do this? Also, thanks for pointing the misspelling.

Comment: @Dave I am not aware of a way to do this, they are very different, based on different measurement methods.

Comment: @whuber Actually there are no missing data. I have a numerical column with values that contains the measured values and another with the corresponding units. Data are "stacked".  What I have are several measurements made in different places using different methods. Only my response variable is all in the same unit.

Comment: @whuber now I think both questions are closed.